# How Do I Start Again With My Rails Project From a Local Git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, devise

I have searched for an answer here and I am getting more and more frustrated!! I'm sure it will be simple for you but I cannot figure it out.

I am following a relatively simple 'Pin type' app tutorial but when I get to installing Devise it just doesn't work. Rather than keep trying to solve that I simply want to revert my project to a previous git add. and git commit, which I assume is stored locally within my /pin_board/.git folder??

Please can somebody help me to get my current project at /rubystack/projects/pin_board back to how it was when I did the git add . then the git commit -am "********".

Thank you so much!

Stuart

Comment: You mean like `git checkout .`?

Comment: Ah, and `git clean -f` after that as well in case you have some untracked files in initializers. :)

Answer (score 0):

run `git log` and copy log id

then

## This will destroy any local modifications.

```
git reset --hard 'yourlogid'
```

**Updated**: if you want to reset last commit then use this

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: You could just do `git reset --hard HEAD`, no commit required.

Comment: @BroiSatse it will rest  last commit I guess , but when you want to rest till specific log at that time it is good to use log id , correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: then you are correct. In the question however he wants to revert to the last commit. :)